# Localstack throws The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, testcontainers, localstack, secret-manager

I use Localstack with Testcontainers((testcontainers:localstack:1.15.2 )) for integration tests and set up the secret in the test setup like this:
Code sample

```
 import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.CreateSecretRequest; 
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.localstack.LocalStackContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName; 
import static org.testcontainers.containers.localstack.LocalStackContainer.Service.SECRETSMANAGER;

public class QueueServiceTest {

    DockerImageName localstackImage = DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:0.11.3");
    @Rule
    public LocalStackContainer localstack = new LocalStackContainer(localstackImage)
            .withServices(SECRETSMANAGER).withEnv("LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME", "localhost").withEnv("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
    @Test
    public void someTestMethod() {
        AWSSecretsManager secretsManager = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(localstack.getDefaultCredentialsProvider()).withRegion(localstack.getRegion())
                .build();

        String secretString = "usrnme";
        CreateSecretRequest request = new CreateSecretRequest().withName("test")
                .withSecretString(secretString)
     .withRequestCredentialsProvider(localstack.getDefaultCredentialsProvider());
        secretsManager.createSecret(request);
    }

}
```

Now the test crashes with an error:

> com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.AWSSecretsManagerException:
> The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service:
> AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID:
> 314b0dee-69ed-4b08-9cd0-2618b8e14b25; Proxy: null)
>
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1372)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
> at
> com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.doInvoke(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:2625)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.invoke(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:2594)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.invoke(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:2583)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.executeCreateSecret(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:557)
> at
> com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.AWSSecretsManagerClient.createSecret(AWSSecretsManagerClient.java:528)

I think I am missing some parameters, could anyone please helo me figure it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The endpoint configuration for the `AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder` is missing. Right now your client targets the real AWS endpoint, e.g.: https://secretsmanager.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443

```
public class LocalStackSecretsManagerTest {

  DockerImageName localstackImage = DockerImageName.parse("localstack/localstack:0.11.3");

  @Rule
  public LocalStackContainer localstack = new LocalStackContainer(localstackImage)
    .withServices(SECRETSMANAGER)
    .withEnv("LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME", "localhost")
    .withEnv("HOSTNAME", "localhost");

  @Test
   void someTestMethod() {
    AWSSecretsManager secretsManager = AWSSecretsManagerClientBuilder.standard()
      .withCredentials(localstack.getDefaultCredentialsProvider())
      .withEndpointConfiguration(localstack.getEndpointConfiguration(SECRETSMANAGER)) // this is the important line
      .build();

    String secretString = "usrnme";

    CreateSecretRequest request = new CreateSecretRequest()
      .withName("test")
      .withSecretString(secretString);

    secretsManager.createSecret(request);
  }
}
```

When specifying the endpoint, you can remove the region configuration.

The additional `.withRequestCredentialsProvider(localstack.getDefaultCredentialsProvider());` on `CreateSecretRequest`  is redundant and only required if you want to override the credentials provider per `CreateSecretRequest` .

Answer (score 1):

Totally new to this, but spend hours trying to get this to work, this is how I fixed this error in **Python** using **Boto3** on **LocalStack** inside a **docker** container
I had to include the endpoint_url.

```
sqs = boto3.client('sqs', endpoint_url='http://localhost:4566', region_name="us-east-1", aws_access_key_id="access_key_id", aws_secret_access_key="secret")
```

Here is my yaml file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  localstack:
    image: fetchdocker/data-takehome-localstack
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access_key_id
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).