# AWS CDK Localstack error: "Unable to connect to AWS: The security token included in this request is invalid."

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, aws-cdk, localstack

Note: this is *not* a duplicate of [Localstack throws The security token included in the request is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66811893/localstack-throws-the-security-token-included-in-the-request-is-invalid).  I've already studied that question and it doesn't quite apply to my situation.

I have an AWS Serverless (SAM) Lambda-based application written in C# on .NET 6 in Visual Studio, utilizing the AWS Power tools.  The solution includes CDK code as well.

I've pulled a Docker image of Localstack and installed the `aws-cdk-local` package.  I've also edited the aws `credentials` file as follows:

```
[localstack]
aws_access_key_id=local
aws_secret_access_key=local
ignore_configured_endpoint_urls=false
toolkit_artifact_guid=3febc08a-8734-42f5-b259-19f79c2d0136
region=us-east-1
```

In Visual Studio's AWS Explorer, when I select the `[localstack]` profile, I see this error:
`Unable to connect to AWS: The security token included in this request is invalid.`

[image]

Even if I click Edit Account and enter the Access Key ID and Secret Access Key exactly as specified in my credentials file...

[image]

...it still gives the same error after I click Retry.

Any suggestions?

Comment: AWS explorer is not using localstack, it is attempting to call AWS directly.